# Variable templates with incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, variable-templates

Suppose we have the following code:

```cpp
struct foo;

struct bar {
    static foo mem;
    template <typename> static foo tpl_mem;
};

using mem_t = decltype(bar::mem);               // (1)
using tpl_mem_t = decltype(bar::tpl_mem<int>);  // (2)
```

It is my understanding that the `static` specifier in both cases makes it a declaration (and not definition), thus I'm allowed to both write the code above and use those members in the decltype's unevaluated context. However, MSVC (v19.37) won't compile `(2)`, complaining about "undefined struct foo", while perfectly compiling `(1)`. Every other compiler I've tested this with (namely, gcc 13, clang 16, and icx 2023.2) compiles both aliases with no problem.

In the following case:

```cpp
struct foo;

extern foo var;
template <typename> extern foo tpl_var;

using var_t = decltype(var);
using tpl_var_t = decltype(tpl_var<int>);
```

MSVC (and others) see no problem. However, if I add a specialization:

```cpp
template <> extern foo tpl_var<double>;  // (3)
```

then both MSVC and GCC complaint, but about different things. MSVC again sees "undefined struct foo", and GCC doesn't like the `extern` there since "explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class". Clang and icx compile it fine though.

So my questions are:

1. Is the code in the first and the second blocks (without the last specialization) and my assumptions about it correct?
2. Is the specialization correct (i.e., can I use `extern` there?), or is GCC right about it?

([everything in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fannTf39a))

**UPDATE:** Surprisingly enough, GCC sees no problem with `extern` in a partial specialization. The following works everywhere, except for MSVC:

```cpp
template <typename T> extern foo tpl_var<std::vector<T>>;
```